# How to improvise singleton for inherited classes?

Tags: unity-game-engine, singleton

```
class A
 {
     public static A Instance {get; private set;}

     protected virtual void Awake()
     {
         Instance = this;
     }
 }

 class B : A
 {
     protected override void Awake()
     {
         base.Awake();
     }

     public void Bmethod()
     {
         //do smth
     }
 }

 class C
 {
     private void SomeMethod()
     {
         B.Instance.Bmethod();
     }
 }
```

So, this is the example. I KNOW this is impossible. **My question is how can I achieve this in a similar way, not too long?**

I came up with an idea but still think there's got to be another one, better.

```
class C
 {
     private void SomeMethod()
     {
         B.Instance.gameObject.GetComponent<B>().Bmethod();
     }
 }
```

Comment: One way is to create the Instance variable in the derived classes. But this means if I have 104238 derived clases I will have to create 104238 Instance variables. So it works but it's not effective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always have a generic class that creates my singletons. I create an abstract class first, something like this:

```
using UnityEngine;

public abstract class MySingleton<T> : ClassYouWantToInheritFrom where T : MySingleton<T>
{
    static T _instance;
    public static T Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if(_instance == null) _instance = (T) FindObjectOfType(typeof(T));
            if(_instance == null) Debug.LogError("An instance of " + typeof(T) +  " is needed in the scene, but there is none.");
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    protected void Awake()
    {
        if     ( _instance == null) _instance = this as T;
        else if(_instance != this ) Destroy(this);
    }
}
```

Now, you put this script somewhere in your project and never touch it again.

To create a singleton that inherits ClassYouWantToInheritFrom you make your class inherit from MySingleton< MyClass > instead of just ClassYouWantToInheritFrom, because MySingleton already inherits it.
And thus:

```
public class MyClass : MySingleton<MyClass>
{
}
```

instead of

```
public class MyClass : ClassYouWantToInheritFrom
{
}
```

Hope this helps :)